# How to stop an asynchronous function without using a global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have some callback function for a click event of which content's look something like this:

```
import functions from 'functions.js'
try
{
    for(var foo in functions)
    {
        await foo()
    }
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log(err)
}
```

What I want to do is have each function run asynchronously in the loop, but be able to stop the execution of `foo` by using another event that could say, throw an error inside the `try` statement so it doesn't crash the whole program. I want the solution to be outside of each `foo` so that it doesn't depend on what exactly `foo` is doing at the current moment.

I know if this was C or something, I could just run the function on another thread or in another process that could be killed, but I'm not aware of anything like that existing in JavaScript. Do you guys know of a solution to this problem ?

Comment: you can use a custom event

Comment: So, your onclick function is performing a static import? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: some cancellation discussion here: [How to use the AbortController to cancel Promises in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187515/how-to-use-the-abortcontroller-to-cancel-promises-in-react) (not React specific)

Comment: It's not possible to stop the execution of `foo()` without modifying the `foo` function. All you can do is stop the loop.

Comment: @Josh No, just couldn't think of a better way to abstract it at the time. What I do is use a `require` statement to pull in some exports from a folder of other .JS files, and one of those exports is a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot terminate the main js thread, however, you can run each function in a web worker and call `worker.terminate()` whether appropriate.

Here's an example: we make 100 requests to jsonplaceholder in a worker, a click on the button stops the whole thing.

```js
let currentWorker = null;

async function runInWebWorker(func) {
  let code = `
    ${func};
    ${func.name}().then(r => self.postMessage(r))
  `
  const blob = new Blob([code], { type: 'application/javascript' });
  
  currentWorker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    currentWorker.onmessage = e => resolve(e.data) 
  )
}

//

async function get100posts() {
  let posts = []
  for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log('fetching', i)
    posts.push(await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + i).then(r => r.json()))
 }
  return posts;
}

//

console.log('working...')

runInWebWorker(get100posts).then(r => console.log(r))

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => currentWorker.terminate()
```

```html
<button>stop</button>
```

Comment: If they're all `fetch()` calls it seems more straight forward to pass an AbortController and link it to the click. But for other arbitrary async work a worker seems good.

Comment: Ahh never even heard of a web worker before. Thanks for the response! I'll try to implement something using this.